# Owner of an Organization with Azure Devops is inactive - How to assign an active user as owner?

Tags: admin, ownership, project-organization

We use Azure with 3 different organization and with 1 project created each and within several teams
The first organization only had one owner and this person in now inactive in our company and therefore doesn't have access. However as we are using this for our projects and 4 different teams, we would like to have one or more active owners assigned to it?

Now the easy question, how can we assign an active member as owner to this organization when the current owner is inactive?

Explanation how to assign active user as an owner to the organization we are using.

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for us
(you need to have AD Admin rights for this):

1. go to Portal.azure.com
2. Manage Azure AD
3. Roles and administrators
4. Select role: Azure DevOps Administrator
5. Add a User who is not a member/ administrator of the organization you want to 'claim'
6. Go to the dev.azure.com/{organization name}
7. Login with the credentials of the account you just added as Azure DevOps Administrator
8. Claim access
9. !Important: current owners needs to be inactive!

Let me know if it worked!